# Return sequence with elements from array A except those that are present in B p times

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I want to write a function that receives two sequences: A and B and returns sequence C which should contain all elements from A (in order) except those that are present in B p times.

For example sequences

A=[2,3,9,2,5,1,3,7,10]

B=[2,1,3,4,3,10,6,6,1,7,10,10,10]

Should return
C=[2,9,2,5,7,10]

When p = 2

I wrote it like this:

```
function cSequence(a, b, p) {
  const times = {};
  b.forEach((item) => {
    if (times[item]) {
      times[item] += 1;
    } else {
      times[item] = 1;
    }
  });
  const pTimes = b.filter((item) => (times[item] == p ? true : false));
  return a.filter((item) => !pTimes.includes(item));
}
```

But is there a better way to make this in terms of time complexity?

Also, should my solution be expressed as O(3n) or O(n)?

Comment: `O(3n)`=`O(n)`.

Comment: "*is there a better way to make this in terms of time complexity?*" - don't use `includes()` inside the `filter` callback! That makes it a quadratic time complexity. You already have a lookup map by item, just use that directly to achieve a linear solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to make this in terms of time complexity?

Don't use `includes()` inside the `filter` callback! That gives it a quadratic time complexity. You already have a lookup map by item, just use that directly to achieve a linear solution! Get rid of the intermediate `pTimes`:

```
function cSequence(a, b, p) {
  const times = {};
  for (const item of b) {
    if (item in times) {
      times[item] += 1;
    } else {
      times[item] = 1;
    }
  }
  return a.filter(item => times[item] != p);
}
```

> Should my solution be expressed as `O(3n)` or `O(n)`?

That's the same. Constant factors are ignored in Landau notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create `bHash` object that contains all the total number occurrences

And then, [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array `A` excluding those elements that are repeated in array `B` `p` times

Code:

```js
const A = [2,3,9,2,5,1,3,7,10]
const B = [2,1,3,4,3,10,6,6,1,7,10,10,10]
const p = 2

const cSequence = (arrA, arrB, p) => {
  const bHash = arrB.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] ??= 0, a[c]++, a), {})
  return arrA.filter(n => bHash[n] !== p)
}

console.log(cSequence(A, B, p))
```